# Moving feral cats’ food

Tags: cats, feeding, feral

My Mom was feeding four ferals and had them TNR’d .  She passed away last year, and a neighbor has continued to feed them daily at my Mom’s house.  I have been there on weekends for the last eight months and have gotten to know them.  They typically lay on her front porch or in the yard most of the day.  They do not come to close to you, and they won’t let you touch them, but they do seem to be interested in humans.

Anyway, I am now putting the house up for sale and cannot continue to feed them there. We have picked up the food and moved it around the corner to the neighbor’s house, based on a recommendation I received from a feral cat rescue group.  They said the cats will smell the food and will find it there.  I haven’t heard that they’ve found It yet (it’s been 3 days) and wonder if anyone has any experience with this type of situation and can offer advice.

Of course, I am hoping the new owners will feed them and continue to let them live on the property.  I am planning to offer to help with the cost since I know what they eat and how much.

**The goal is to make sure they have food and fresh water available to them in the event the new owner doesn’t put food out for them.**

Comment: What is your goal in moving their food?

Comment: The goal is to make sure they have food and fresh water available to them in the event the new owner doesn’t put food out for them.

Comment: Has the neighbor agreed to provide them with food and water? Or are you arbitrarily moving the dishes?

Comment: Yes, I am providing the neighbor with the food. I live an hour away so will send it to her.  I have only good intentions and want only what is best for the cats. Posted here as I was hoping for suggestions or advice that I haven’t come up with yet. Thank you for your comments.